# Random Sample selection in R data frame starting at a random row

Tags: r, random, row

I have to select a number of rows at specific intervals from a data frame randomly. Suppose if I have to select 10 rows, from a data frame with 50 rows, I have to select every 5th row.  But my starting point will vary randomly, say sometime it will be 8th row or even 37th row.  The following is the code I am using:

if df is my data.frame:

```
randomRow <- 37       #assuming I am starting at the 37th row
nofRows <- 5          #number of rows that I have to select out of 50 rows
totRows <- nrow(df)
freq <- as.numeric(format(round(totRows/nofRows), nsmall = 0))       #calculating the frequency interval

#code to subset

df[seq(randomRow, nrow(df), freq), ]
```

The problem is if I start at 37th row the fetch stops at 50th row (end of my df), and is not looping around from 1st row to 36th row.  Don't know if I have to use a for loop.  Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try

```
v1 <- c(randomRow:totRows, seq(randomRow-1))
df[v1[seq(1, length(v1), by = freq)],]
```

Comment: thank you @akrun... however I am getting the following error:  `Error in seq.default(randomRow, totRows, by = freq) : 
  wrong sign in 'by' argument`

Comment: @LeArNr Based on your example I am not getting any error, assuming that `totRows <- 50`

Comment: @akrun...apologies....my randomRow value was out of range...when I adjusted I am getting an output all with NA's ...will come back to you after checking it at my end

Comment: @LeArNr As I mentioned earlier, I am using your example and it works.  Not sure why you are selecting `randomRow` that is not in the dataset, if you have a dataset with 50 rows, and the `randomRow` selected is 454, it won't work.  May be you can wrap this in a function and use `stopifnot` for strange cases.